# http.get nodejs lambda wrong encoding for png image

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, lambda, encoding

I am using node.js (aws lambda) to perform a simple get request for a .png image on an external server.  The data that I'm getting back seems to be encoded incorrectly, but I cant figure out how or why to get the correct encoding.  the length and structure of the data seems to be the same (as shown in the images), but I just cant figure out why I dont get the same data...ive tried converting to base64, utf-8, etc.

my function:

```
http.get(FinalURL, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(d) {
                body += d;
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                resolve(body);
            });
            res.on('error', function(e) {
                resolve(e.message);
            });
        });
```

[INCORRECT ENCODING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A57pP.png)

[CORRECT ENCODING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTMAJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by downloading it as binary using

```
res.setEncoding('binary');
```

i think this simplifies the characters and then its able to understand what its downloading